# html form submission and loading configuration file data into form field using c

Tags: html, c

What I'm  trying to do is, on html form submission a configuration file is created on the server and the html form field is updated with the configuration file data. Right now I am able to create a configuration file. Can anyone help me with the form field part?. I need to do it with html and c. 
`

```
int main(void)
{
    char *lenstr;
    char input[MAXINPUT], data[MAXINPUT];
    long len;
    printf("%s%c%c\n",
    "Content-Type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1",13,10);
    printf("<TITLE>Response</TITLE>\n");
    lenstr = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");
    if(lenstr == NULL || sscanf(lenstr,"%ld",&len)!=1 || len > MAXLEN)
    {
        printf("<P>Error in invocation - wrong FORM probably.");
    }
    else
    {
        FILE *f;
        fgets(input, len+1, stdin);
        unencode(input+EXTRA, input+len, data);
        f = fopen(DATAFILE, "w+");
        if(f == NULL)
        {
            printf("<P>Sorry, cannot store your data.");
        }
        else
        {
            fputs(data, f);
        }
        fclose(f);
        printf("<P>Thank you! The following contribution of yours has \
                been saved:<BR>%s",data);
     }
     return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: What happens when this program runs? What problem does it give you? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to elaborate on the problem. Like adding what output you get from the program and what you expected?What, if anything, get written to the file and what did you expect? What is the "input" passed to the program? And if e.g. `fopen` fails, have you checked *why*? You could check it by checking `errno`.

Comment: The server process receives the form, and so the server process must spawn your program. Following that, the server process must know a config file has ben created, read it and send the updated form. Seems it is all at the server process...